# Label display CSS changing associated textbox position

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using Label and textbox and changing label display property on demand.
Both are draggable at once so that i kept that in one div.

```
<div id="textbox" style="position:absolute;border:1px solid black" class="screen">
<label id="lbltext">Name</label>    
<input id="text1"  type="text" />
```

But if i change display property of label then associated textbox changes position. I just want to change only  label position.

Can Anybody give me some pointer on this?

**Jquery :**

```
 $("#block").click(function(){
$("#lbltext").css("display", "block");
});

$("#none").click(function(){
$("#lbltext").css("display", "");
});

$("#blank").click(function(){
$("#lbltext").css("display", "none");
});
```

**[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oj0xvuyb/)**

**[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oj0xvuyb/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the label to continue to take up space even when hidden then use `visibility: hidden` rather than `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

Like LodeRunner28 said you can use "visibility", when you want to keep the space.

**JQuery:**

```
$("#block").click(function(){
$("#lbltext").css("visibility", "visible");
});

$("#blank").click(function(){
$("#lbltext").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

**[Updated your JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oj0xvuyb/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but  needed same operation as i mentioned in jsfiddle demo without changing textbox position.

Comment: Do you mean you have to use display property? And what is the difference between display = "" and display = "none" if the textbox can't change position?